# sed vs. awk: Read a file line by line and append to a specific line in another file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, yaml

Consider two files below `users.txt`:

```
Arnold.Bosch
David.Ledru
Mehri.Sunny
```

and `docker-compose.txt`:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  strongswan-server:
    image: vpn-strongswan
    container_name: strongswan-server

    networks:
      strongswan-server:
    environment:
      - STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=
    sysctls:
    volumes:
    ports:
      - 500:500/udp
      - 4500:4500/udp
volumes:
  strongswan-server-conf:
networks:
  strongswan-server:
```

The following script uses `sed` filter to add a new user to the end of the specific line containing `STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS`.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "Text read from file: $line"
  
    sed -i "10s/$/ $line/" $2

done < "$1"
```

```
environment:
  - STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=Arnold.Bosch David.Ledru Mehri.Sunny
```

I was wondering is there another way to achieve this based on `awk`?

Comment: In your example, `users` is never replaced but disappears.

Comment: @FelixJN thank you for your attention. Yes, but please ignore for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to do what you say you want to do and your code does, i.e. append to the end of the STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS line:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{users=users OFS $0; next} /STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=/{$0=$0 users} 1' users.txt docker-compose.txt
version: '3.9'
services:
  strongswan-server:
    image: vpn-strongswan
    container_name: strongswan-server

    networks:
      strongswan-server:
    environment:
      - STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=users Arnold.Bosch David.Ledru Mehri.Sunny
    sysctls:
    volumes:
    ports:
      - 500:500/udp
      - 4500:4500/udp
volumes:
  strongswan-server-conf:
networks:
  strongswan-server:
```

Comment: Yes, your solution works as expected for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `jq` wrapper `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/ to read the `docker-compose.txt` YAML file, locate the correct part of the right array in the document structure and replace it with the data read from the `users.txt` file:

```bash
yq -y -n '
    input | (
        .services."strongswan-server".environment[] | 
        select(startswith("STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS="))
    ) = "STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=" + input' docker-compose.txt users.txt
```

This disables the default reading of all input using `-n` and instead reads the first input file with the first `input` instruction in the `jq` expression.  Once that is read, the `environment` array is iterated over, looking for any text element that starts with the text `STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=`.  Once found, this is replaced by the string `STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=` followed by whatever is found in the second input file.

The result given the data in the question:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  strongswan-server:
    image: vpn-strongswan
    container_name: strongswan-server
    networks:
      strongswan-server: null
    environment:
      - STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=Arnold.Bosch David.Ledru Mehri.Sunny
    sysctls: null
    volumes: null
    ports:
      - 500:500/udp
      - 4500:4500/udp
volumes:
  strongswan-server-conf: null
networks:
  strongswan-server: null
```

A shorter variant which always sets the *first* element of the `environment` array:

```bash
yq -y -n 'input | .services."strongswan-server".environment[0] = "STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=" + input'  docker-compose.txt users.txt
```

The `-y` option to `yq` selects YAML output.  Without it, you'll get JSON output (and with `-t` TOML, and with `-x` XML).

Comment: Merci for introducing `yq` to me. It's really sed of YAML files.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `tr`

```
$ sed "s/- STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=/&$(tr '\n' ' ' < users.txt)/" docker-compose.txt
version: '3.9'
services:
  strongswan-server:
    image: vpn-strongswan
    container_name: strongswan-server

    networks:
      strongswan-server:
    environment:
      - STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=Arnold.Bosch David.Ledru Mehri.Sunny 
    sysctls:
    volumes:
    ports:
      - 500:500/udp
      - 4500:4500/udp
volumes:
  strongswan-server-conf:
networks:
  strongswan-server:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STEP1:

rep=$(perl -pne "s/\n/ /g" f1)

STEP2:

sed -i "/STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=/s/.*/&$rep/g" f2
```

output

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  strongswan-server:
    image: vpn-strongswan
    container_name: strongswan-server

    networks:
      strongswan-server:
    environment:
      - STRONGSWAN_CLIENTS=Arnold.Bosch David.Ledru Mehri.Sunny 
    sysctls:
    volumes:
    ports:
      - 500:500/udp
      - 4500:4500/udp
volumes:
  strongswan-server-conf:
networks:
  strongswan-server:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer +1. Cloud you please explain what does the STEP1 do?